# Remove Key from json/Dict Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Iam trying to remove some key,value from my json output, but none of the things seems to be working.

The code solution is basically to convert a csv to json and then removed the unwanted keys from it.

```
import csv, json
import pandas as pd
import os

def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    data = {}
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader:
            
            key = rows['ipadd']
            data[key] = rows
            #used del but not working as expected
            #del data['number']
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


csvFilePath = r'csvfile.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'demo.json'

make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I tried with `del data['key_name']`.
Thought of manipulate csv before json creation, but then the key wouldnt be available for json creation.

```
{
    "some_random_key": {
        "number": "12345",
        "ipadd": "some_random_key",
        "version": "0",
        "name": "superman",
        "devicename": "0",
        "osversion": "0"
    },
    "some_random_key2": {
        "number": "54321",
        "ipadd": "some_random_key2",
        "version": "0",
        "name": "batman",
        "devicename": "0",
        "osversion": "0"
    }
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
    "some_random_key": {
        "version": "0",
        "name": "superman",
        "devicename": "0",
        "osversion": "0"
    },
    "some_random_key2": {
        "version": "0",
        "name": "batman",
        "devicename": "0",
        "osversion": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: _I tried with del data['key_name']. Thought of manipulate csv before json creation, but then the key wouldnt be available for json creation_ - duplicate the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `dict.pop()`, which does exactly what you need.